# Redirecting a local network path to the local disk

Tags: windows, networking, redirection, local

I have a computer in a network that automatically tries to open a local network path, like:

*\\bbserver\storage\dir*

I would like to redirect this network directory to my local hard drive, so that every time Windows tries to open that directory, it will be redirected to a local folder (C:\localdir)

As far as I could find, I know that I have to edit the lmhosts.sam file, located in system32\drivers\etc. I read all the documentation provided in the file, but I still don't know how to set it up in order to do what I want.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: If no computer on the network is called bbserver, and you rename yours that way, the connection should go through and loop on itself. You still need to create a share called storage somewhere on the disk.

Comment: Yes, I would like to redirect everything on my local disk. I don't care about the name...